# tabItem deactivation of menuItem when menuSubItems present in ShinyDashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

When developing a ShinyDashboard sidebar it appears that for some reason whenever you add **menuSubItem**s to a **menuItem**, the content relative to the parent **menuItem** **tabName** is disabled.  The default content appears to become that of one of the **menuSubItem**'s.  I want data (In this case the words *Show Me!* [line 62]) displayed from the **tabItem** when clicking on Menu One.  Clicking only activates the sliding functionality.

There was question surrounding menu and sub-menu refresh. I've modified that code accordingly.

```
library('shiny')
library('shinydashboard')
# Sidebar #############################
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
 tags$head(
    tags$script(
      HTML(
        "
        $(document).ready(function(){
          // Bind classes to menu items, easiet to fill in manually
          var ids = ['subItemOne','subItemTwo','subItemThree','subItemFour','menuOne','menuTwo'];
          for(i=0; i<ids.length; i++){
            $('a[data-value='+ids[i]+']').addClass('my_subitem_class');
          }

          // Register click handeler
          $('.my_subitem_class').on('click',function(){
            // Unactive menuSubItems
            $('.my_subitem_class').parent().removeClass('active');
          })
        })
        "
      )
    )
  ),
  width = 290,

  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem('Menu One', tabName = 'menuOne', icon = icon('line-chart'), 
        collapsible = 
            menuSubItem('Sub-Item One', tabName = 'subItemOne'),
            menuSubItem('Sub-Item Two', tabName = 'subItemTwo')
            )
  ),

  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem('Menu Two', tabName = 'menuTwo', icon = icon('users')
            # collapsible = 
           #    menuSubItem('Sub-Item Three', tabName = 'subItemThree'),
          #   menuSubItem('Sub-Item Four', tabName = 'subItemFour')
    )
  )

)
# Body #############################
body <- dashboardBody(

  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = 'subItemOne',
            h2('Selected Sub-Item One')
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = 'subItemTwo',
            h2('Selected Sub-Item Two')
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = 'subItemThree',
            h2('Selected Sub-Item Three')
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = 'subItemFour',
            h2('Selected Sub-Item Four')
    ),
 tabItem(tabName = 'menuOne',
            h2('Show Me!')
    ),
 tabItem(tabName = 'menuTwo',
            h2('m2')
    )

  )
)
# UI #############################
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = 'Test', titleWidth = 290),
  sidebar,
  body
)
# Server #############################
server <- function(input, output){

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I want my cake and eat it too with this one!  Thanks.